# How do I insert an already uploaded video file into my Media Library?

Tags: uploads

I'm having problems with the WP uploader (hosting issue); WP is pooping out after uploading files that are relatively large (> 32MB).

**My idea was to upload the video file via SFTP to the server and then try to get WP to insert it into the Media Library. How do I do this?**

I know that it isn't as simple as just putting it into `wp-content/uploads/<date-path>/` because there is some meta-data to add to the back-end DB.

I've seen some posts for `media_sideload_image` but looking at the code, it looks like this is specifically for images. I looked at `media_handle_sideload` but I'm not sure how it works or how to create a solution to insert this file where it needs to go. For example, the comments say:

> @param array $file_array Array similar to a {@link $_FILES} upload array

What does `{@link $_FILES} upload array` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) will do this for you